# Iterating through object with key/value map

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the rest api, I get an object like this:

```
          response =  {
                        "0": [
                                    {
                                        "description": "basket",
                                        "color": "red"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "description": "pillow",
                                        "color": "blue"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "description": "armchair",
                                        "color": "white"
                                    }
                               ],
                         "1" : [
                                        {
                                            "description": "shirt",
                                            "color": "black"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "description": "pants",
                                            "color": "blue"
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
```

This is what I need to display in my view:
[image]

```
// controller.js

self.catKeys= Object.keys(response)
self.catValue= Object.values(response)
```

// view.html

```
  <div ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.catKeys" class="col-md-3"> {{ cat }} </div>

  <div ng-repeat="val in ctrl.catValue" class="col-md-9">
    {{ val[index].description }} {{ val[index].color}}
  </div>
```

I've also tried many other things but I just cannot get it..please help :(

Comment: what are you getting right now

Comment: @cmgchess nothing just errors. Is this really that hard lol?

Comment: https://codepen.io/cmgchess/pen/bGxyLep as a starter. see if u can get things working

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#map` to concatenate each item with its color, then `join` it into one string.

```js
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(response)) {
  response[k] = v.map(x => x.color + ' ' + x.description).join(' - ');
}
self.response = response;
```

Then, displaying is simple:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in ctrl.response" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">{{k}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">{{v}}</div>
</div>
```